# Splitting Apache Log from File

Tags: regex, scala, apache-spark

I have an Apache log such as:

```
179.50.40.12 - - [26/Aug/2019:08:38:54 -0400] "POST /wp-login.php HTTP/1.1" 403 1139 "-" "Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Ubuntu; Linux x86_64; rv:62.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/62.0"
139.51.75.162 - - [26/Aug/2019:09:19:32 -0400] "GET /wp-login.php HTTP/1.1" 200 1336 "-" "Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Ubuntu; Linux x86_64; rv:62.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/62.0"
139.51.75.162 - - [26/Aug/2019:09:19:36 -0400] "POST /wp-login.php HTTP/1.1" 403 0 "-" "Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Ubuntu; Linux x86_64; rv:62.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/62.0"
77.22.40.199 - - [26/Aug/2019:10:15:16 -0400] "GET /wp-login.php HTTP/1.1" 200 11527 "-" "Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Ubuntu; Linux x86_64; rv:62.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/62.0"
77.22.40.199 - - [26/Aug/2019:10:15:17 -0400] "POST /wp-login.php HTTP/1.1" 403 1139 "-" "Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Ubuntu; Linux x86_64; rv:62.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/62.0"
```

I've tried to use `split` as such:

```
val logs = spark.read.format("text").load("/logs/20190826.log")
val pattern = """^(\S+) (\S+) (\S+) \[([\w:/]+\s[+\-]\d{4})\] "(\S+)\s?(\S+)?\s?(\S+)?" (\d{3}|-) (\d+|-)\s?"?([^"]*)"?\s?"?([^"]*)?"?$"""
val logs_parsed = logs.withColumn("value", split($"value", pattern))
                      .withColumn("IP", $"value"(1))
                      .withColumn("Timestamp", $"value"(4))
logs_parsed.show()
```

Which returns

```
+-----+---+---------+
|value| IP|Timestamp|
+-----+---+---------+
| [, ]|   |     null|
| [, ]|   |     null|
| [, ]|   |     null|
| [, ]|   |     null|
| [, ]|   |     null|
+-----+---+---------+
```

The goal is to split with the regex capture groups and map with column names.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If anyone has a more elegant solution, I'm open to it. Otherwise, here is one using `regexp_extract`

```
val lgp = logs.withColumn("ip", regexp_extract($"value", pattern, 1))
              .withColumn("timestamp", regexp_extract($"value", pattern, 4))
              .withColumn("req_method", regexp_extract($"value", pattern, 5))
              .withColumn("req_resource", regexp_extract($"value", pattern, 6))
              .withColumn("protocol", regexp_extract($"value", pattern, 7))
              .withColumn("status", regexp_extract($"value", pattern, 8))
              .withColumn("size", regexp_extract($"value", pattern, 9))
              .withColumn("referer", regexp_extract($"value", pattern, 10))
              .withColumn("agent", regexp_extract($"value", pattern, 11))
              .drop("value")
              .show()
```